# CSS Grid not aligning

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple page with CSS Grid.
The result is pretty good before inserting a php function with MySQL.

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <br>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <br>
            <?php if ($fetch['file_name'] == '') { ?>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="../images/missing.png" alt="Sample image" style="height:150px; width:150px;">
            <?php } else { ?>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="../images/<?php echo $fetch['file_name']; ?>" alt="missing.png" style="height:150px; width:150px;"/>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="caption">
                <h4><?php echo $fetch['school_name']; ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $fetch['email']; ?></p>
                <p class="lead">$21.000</p>
                <a class="btn2" href="profileorg.php?Org_ID=<?php echo $fetch['Org_ID'] ?>">View profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The screenshot is below

This is my problem:

**After inserting php function**
[image: After inserting php function]

What I want is grid align like this:

**Reference**
[image: Reference]

Comment: You have one PHP closing brace too much `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Also a tip, use alternative syntax for templates. Not `<?php if (true) { ?> <?php } ?>` but `<?php if (true): ?> <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="container text-center">
    <br>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <br>
            <?php if ($fetch['file_name'] == '') { ?>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="../images/missing.png" alt="Sample image" style="height:150px; width:150px;">
            <?php } else { ?>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="../images/<?php echo $fetch['file_name']; ?>" alt="missing.png" style="height:150px; width:150px;"/>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="caption">
                <h4><?php echo $fetch['school_name']; ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $fetch['email']; ?></p>
                <p class="lead">$21.000</p>
                <a class="btn2" href="profileorg.php?Org_ID=<?php echo $fetch['Org_ID'] ?>">View profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

probably its because you have inserted extra closing braces. This code will work fine you.

Comment: When I delete that closing braces, it will say "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 73"

Comment: According to the code snippet you provided, that bracket shouldn't be there. You might have opening bracket that somewhere at top. According to screen shot you provided, it seems that, <br> tag is causing your div to move down. Try removing <br> from your code snippet.

Comment: Damn! I was not thinking about that. Haha, thanks for the fix. I'm laughing. Thank you so much, it was fixed.